# How can I replay a TCP stream to my client

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, tcp, pcap

I need to do some validation testing of a new feed handler I have made. I have some pcap data that I captured from the production network and I would like to have my development feed handler connect to the "replay" of this data and compare the results.

My pcap:
I have a prod application that connects to a data feed, a TCP connection to an external server lets call assume this is 123.456.789.1:1234. This external sever then sends data to my application there is almost no client to server communication the server just sends the client data until the client drops. I have a pcap of all the packets sent to and from port 1234. I got this pcap by mirroring the production port (SPAN) on the switch and attaching tcpdump to an interface plugged in to the mirrored network port. When I look at the PCAP in wireshark it has all the data I would expect.

My problem:
I am in no way a network engineer and I am unsure how I can use this pcap to test my application. What I would like to do is "replay" this stream form the pcap and connect to it with my development application to validate that the data is being handled the same was it was on the prod connection.

I would like to some how "replay" the data sent from 123.456.789.1:12344 on 127.0.0.1:1234 and then connect to 127.0.0.1:1234 with my dev application. I looked at tcpreplay but from the documents I can not seem to figure out if it can do this, I get the feeling that they do not handle the tcp session data, and I could do this if it was a UDP stream, but tcpreplay can not act as the external server. Did I read this wrong or is there another tool that will let me do this?

thanks!

Comment: Have you checked out the answer to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834615/tcp-stream-replay-tool)?  Exact TCP replay is in general very difficult.

Comment: I looked at the question, guess I was hoping that since my interaction was more simplistic then his (I do not really have any client -> server communication it is just a connection and listen model) there my be some simple setting on tcpreplay I could use. But guess not I will just dump the data and netcat it as Slartibartfast suggested and was hinted at in the other question too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use netcat if you just want to throw some data back at your tool, and you don't care about what the tool sends.

You would do this by extracting the raw data sent by your tool from the pcap file ([this](http://src.carnivore.it/streams/about) tool may be helpful) and then piping that into netcat.

Comment: As an update for any one that comes along reading this in the future with the same problem. This solution worked for me, but there was a small problem all the data is of course sent as fast as netcat can send it. This destroyed all the buffers I had in my feed handler. Since the exact timing was not really an issue for me as long as the bit-rate was somewhat realistic I just did "cat <data-file> | cpipe -s 500 | nc -l <port>" to limit the rate to 500 KBs. This was fine fore me, but if you need more precise timing you may need another solution.